# Sending an automated email if the date in a cell matches todays date

Tags: date, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get this code to work to send an email when today's date is equal to the date in a certain cell in a google sheet.

The debugging image shows that both 'today' and 'dates' variables are identical, is there something I'm missing?

```
function emailAlert() {
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0); 

  // getting data from spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Master');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,3); 
  var dates = range.getValue();
  dates.setHours(0,0,0,0); 
  var range2 = sheet.getRange(1,8)
  var emails = range2.getValue();

  if(dates == today){

   MailApp.sendEmail(emails,'Test','Test')

  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Compare them by using `getTime()` as comparison between date objects directly doesn't work.

#### Final Code:

```
function emailAlert() {
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0); 
  Logger.log(today);

  // getting data from spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Master');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,3); 
  var dates = range.getValue();
  dates.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  Logger.log(dates);
  var range2 = sheet.getRange(1,8)
  var emails = range2.getValue();

  // using getTime() for comparison
  if(dates.getTime() == today.getTime()){
    Logger.log("sending mail")
    // MailApp.sendEmail(emails,'Test','Test')
  }
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Amazing yes, works perfectly now! Thanks so much. Any idea why date objects aren't comparable but getTime is?

Comment: `getTime` returns a number which represents the time equivalent of the date, that's why it is easy to compare. object comparisons are never a good idea in the first place.

Comment: Hi @joeyrobbins, If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)